# Conditional renderDataTable

Tags: r, shinyapps

In the app there are two actionbutton, "tasto.a" and "tasto.b", if I press the "key.a" button data.frame "a" is assigned to tab.SDO(), if I press the "key.a" button data.frame "a" is assigned to tab.SDO(), so that the chosen data.frame is rendered in the ui. The problem is that only the second assignmentin the list is made (tab.SDO <- eventReactive (input $ key.b, {b})) even if I press the "key.b" key. Is this type of "conditional" assignment correct or am I making some mistakes?

```
require(shiny)

a <- data.frame(a.x = c(1,3,4,5,1,2), a.y = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
b <- data.frame(b.x = c(21,33,44,52,13,27), b.y = c("D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"))


#### UI ####
ui <- navbarPage(title = "FLUSSI SANITARI",
                 theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),     
                 #### Schede di dimissione ospedaliera ####
                 tabPanel(title = "prova", 
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              actionButton("tasto.a", "a"),
                              actionButton("tasto.b", "b")
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              div(DT::dataTableOutput("tabella.SDO"), style = "font-size:80%")
                            )
                          )

                 )
)

#### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  tab.SDO <- eventReactive(input$tasto.a, {a})
  tab.SDO <- eventReactive(input$tasto.b, {b})


  output$tabella.SDO <- DT::renderDataTable({tab.SDO()}, rownames = FALSE,
                                            options = list(pageLength = 25)
  )


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reactive value and some `observeEvent`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  tab.SDO <- reactiveVal(a)
  observeEvent(input$tasto.a, {
    tab.SDO(a)
  })
  observeEvent(input$tasto.b, {
    tab.SDO(b)
  })

  output$tabella.SDO <- DT::renderDataTable({tab.SDO()}, rownames = FALSE,
                                            options = list(pageLength = 25)
  )

}
```